# How to create another viewport only for save to image?

Tags: opengl, viewport

I want to create two viewport.
The first one is for showing as normal does.
The second one is only for save to image like per one minute save to a new image.
How to do that?
Thank you~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two methods you can use:

1) A framebuffer (http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer) which is essentially a second frame that you can do drawing calls on. Any rendering done to the framebuffer is saved to an internal texture object, which you can then grab and do whatever with. As a side note, you can use framebuffers to do full screen effects (bloom, anti-aliasing, etc.)

2) More likely, however, you're looking for glReadPixels (https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glReadPixels.xhtml). This is a quick function call you can do after you're finished your drawing calls but *before* you swap out your buffers (assuming you're drawing with a double-buffered context). This function will copy a selection of pixels from the framebuffer that you just issued your drawing calls to and give them to you in an array, which you can again do whatever you want with. The nice thing about this is you dont have to put up with the hassle of creating a second "viewport" (I think you meant framebuffer?), you can just copy the pixels off of the same framebuffer that you'll eventually show the user.

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Just to be clear, `glReadPixels` does not necessarily have to read from the same buffer as you are drawing into (and it is not what you would call a quick function call usually since it forces a CPU/GPU synchronization unless you use a PBO). It is not particularly useful most of the time if it *does not* do this, but GL actually does maintain a separate Draw and Read buffer state. That is why the manual page you linked to lists [`glReadBuffer`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glReadBuffer.xhtml) under "*see also*".

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Thanks for the tip about Read and Write buffer state, I did not know that. As for glReadPixels beign a slow function, yeah thats true, but I figured since sam's only looking to get an image once per minute, on average the framerate won't suffer that much